# Selecting Camera

Tags: c#, c++

Is it possible to enlist all the camera's connected to the System along with their physical address?

I am not inclined to any particular language, though I prefer C#.

Thanks for help.

Comment: anything is possible with the right API and the right code.

Comment: +1 Specialized knowledge questions that I have no idea how to answer always fascinate me.

Comment: @Muad'Dib that's what I'm searching for, API! :)

Comment: yes, but you didn't ask for an API, you asked if it was possible. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention C#, I'm going to assume you mean on Windows.

From Windows viewpoint, still cameras are almost completely different sorts of things from video cameras (but, interestingly enough, still cameras and scanners are almost the same).

Since you don't mention video, I'm going to also guess you mean still cameras. You normally deal with still cameras (and scanners) via Windows Image Acquisition (WIA). To list cameras, you'd normally use `IStillImage::GetDeviceList`. This will return a `STI_DEVICE_INFORMATION` structure, which includes a `dwHardwareConfiguration` member to tell you the type of interface used (e.g., USB) and `pszPortName` to identify the specific port to which the camera is attached.

If you want to trace back from that port name to something more "physical", such as the bus number and such, you should (probably) be able to use WMI_USBControllerDevice to map from the device back to the controller.

If you want to deal with video cameras, you'd use `capGetDriverDescription` to get a description of each video capture device that's installed. In this case, getting something closer to a "physical" address is considerably more difficult. `capGetDriverDescription` will give you a driver name. I suppose you can do the usual Windows "stuff" to enumerate drivers and match up names to find out something about the driver in question, but I haven't played with that to be sure (for example) which name it gives you (the internal driver name, the display name, or what).

Also note that MS has developed about a half dozen different multimedia interfaces over time, so almost any multimedia cat can be skinned at least a half dozen different ways.

Comment: Thank you for that very good explnanation. I will try using it.